# I am trying to get a monetary value out of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the cost out of a string in sql server.

> JCB 437 3045 (working in Area 100) - Monks Report (Date worked 13.05.15) - Replaced damaged hydraulic hose. (Cost Impact £70.00) *Immediate Action - full investigation required. Team leader to review house keeping of plant following loading activates TBT to be issued regarding cleaning off buckets following loading review of mobile plant check sheet and reporting of Faults (Process manager and H&S)

There will always be a £ sign, but the cost can very in amount up to £99,999
.00

how can I do this and do this efficiently?

Comment: show us what you have thus far...

Comment: Suggest you redesign the databaseand application to put the costs in a separate field.  It is never a good thing to have to extract data from a long description like this.

Comment: I can't as its something we've bought and people have decided to use it this way :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this...

```
    DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(max) 
SET@someString = 'This is just a test string that contains that values of $200.00. This also contains some other text'
 SELECT SUBSTRING(@someString, CHARINDEX('$',@someString), CHARINDEX('.00',@someString) - CHARINDEX('$',@someString)+3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, achieved what I wanted to achieve because of this.